# Strange behaviour of the "M" custom format specifier in c#

Tags: c#, .net, date, string-formatting

This Code produces the output in the comments bellow each Console.WriteLine statement.

Can anyone explain this kind of behaviour?

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 8, 18);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("M"));
// Displays August 18

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("M "));
// Displays 8

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("(M)"));
// Displays (8)

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("(M) MMM, MMMM"));
// Displays (8) Aug, August
```

Comment: M is Month, what's wrong with it?  If you change it by MM you'll get 08

Comment: @McNets yes, I was confused by different output for what I thought was the same format specifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone explain this kind of behaviour?

Yes, it's completely documented in [standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Let's go through them one at a time:

- `date1.ToString("M")`: That uses a single character 'M', so it's the standard format string for "month/day pattern"
- `date1.ToString("M ")`: That uses a format string with two characters, so it's a custom format string using `M` which is the month number, 1-12 with no padding.
- `date1.ToString("(M)")`: Again, a custom format string using `M`
- `date1.ToString("(M) MMM, MMMM")`: A custom format string using `M`, as well as `MMM` ("abbreviated name of the month") and `MMMM` (" full name of the month")

The important difference between the first two is that a format string is *only* considered to be a standard format if it's a single character. Otherwise, it's considered to be a custom format. If you want to use a single-character custom format specifier on its own, you can use `%` as a leading character - so `date1.ToString("%M")` would return "8" rather than "August 18".

Comment: You're right. I missed the part [about using single custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Date and Time in C# are handled by DateTime struct in C# that provides properties and methods to format dates in different datetime formats.

```
M-> Month number(eg.3)

MM-> Month number with leading zero(eg.04)

MMM-> Abbreviated Month Name (e.g. Dec)

MMMM-> Full month name (e.g. December)
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: `DateTime` is a struct, not a class - and this doesn't explain the output of the first line (format string `"M`") or why it differs to the second (format string `"M "`).